# cardinality of the set $\{z\in \Bbb C : z^{98} =1\; and \;z^n\neq1 \;for\; any\; 0\lt n\lt98 \;\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the cardinality of the set $\{z\in \Bbb C : z^{98} =1\; and \;z^n\neq1 \;for\; any\; 0\lt n\lt98 \;\} $ ?

I was thinking about $98^{th}$ roots of unity. Will they somehow help ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "I was thinking about $98^{th}$ roots of unity" - this is a set which contains them; is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that not all but some of them will be in this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the $98$th roots of unity will help here.  Of course, every element of the set **is** a $98$th root of unity, but not all $98$th roots of unity are elements of the set.

Let $\xi = e^{2 \pi i/98}$.  Each $98$th root of unity can be written as $\xi^k$ for some $k$.

> Claim: $\xi^k$ is an element of this set if and only if $k$ is relatively prime to $98$

See if you can prove that this is true.  What you'll need for the cardinality, then, is the *"Euler totient function"*.

Comment: But can't there be elements other than $98{th}$ root of unity in this set ?

Comment: And I have yet not studied "Euler totient function", so is there any other method ?

Comment: @AnuragJain think about it: the *definition* of a 98th root of unity is that any number such that $z^{98} = 1$.  So no, there *can't* be elements here besides $98$th roots of unity.

Comment: @AnuragJain as for the cardinality part: you don't really need to know about the function, I suppose; you just need to count how many of the integers from $1$ to $98$ are relatively prime to $98$, which is a quick combinatorics problem.

Comment: @AnuragJain what you need to do here is count how many numbers from $0$ to $98$ are multiples of $2$ **or** multiples of $7$.  The rest of the numbers are relatively prime to $98$.

Comment: Yeah, that I can do using Eulerphi function.

Comment: "Euler totient function" is another name for the "Euler phi function".

Comment: Oh okie, I had never heard of this before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33251/discussion-between-anurag-jain-and-omnomnomnom).

Answer (score 1):

The 98th roots of unity forms a group under multiplication isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{98}$ so you're simply asking for the number of generators of this group. The answer is $\phi (98) = \phi(2)\cdot \phi(7^2)= 42$.